# how to cut CSV file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, cut

I have the following CSV file

```
 more file.csv

 Number,machine_type,OS,Version,Mem,CPU,HW,Volatge

 1,HG652,linux,23.12,256,III,LOP90,220
 2,HG652,linux,23.12,256,III,LOP90,220
 3,HG652,SCO,MK906G,526,1G,LW1005,220
 4,HG652,solaris,1172,1024,2Core,netra,220
 5,HG652,solaris,1172,1024,2Core,netra,220
```

Please advice how to cut CSV file ( by cut or sed or awk command )

in order to get a partial CSV file

- Command need to get value that represent the fields that we want to cut from the CSV

  According to **example 1** ( value should be **6** )

**Example 1**

on this example we cut the 6 fields from left to right , ( in this case CSV will look like this )

```
  Number,machine_type,OS,Version,Mem,CPU

  1,HG652,linux,23.12,256,III
  2,HG652,linux,23.12,256,III
  3,HG652,SCO,MK906G,526,1G
  4,HG652,solaris,1172,1024,2Core
  5,HG652,solaris,1172,1024,2Core
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cut` is your friend:

```
$ cut -d',' -f-6 file
Number,machine_type,OS,Version,Mem,CPU

1,HG652,linux,23.12,256,III
2,HG652,linux,23.12,256,III
3,HG652,SCO,MK906G,526,1G
4,HG652,solaris,1172,1024,2Core
5,HG652,solaris,1172,1024,2Core
```

#### Explanation

- `-d','` set comma as field separator
- `-f-6` print up to the field number 6 based on that delimiter. It is equivalent to `-f1-6`, as `1` is default.

---

Also `awk` can make it, if necessary:

```
$ awk -v FS="," 'NF{for (i=1;i<=6;i++) printf "%s%s", $i, (i==6?RS:FS)}' file
Number,machine_type,OS,Version,Mem,CPU
1,HG652,linux,23.12,256,III
2,HG652,linux,23.12,256,III
3,HG652,SCO,MK906G,526,1G
4,HG652,solaris,1172,1024,2Core
5,HG652,solaris,1172,1024,2Core
```

Comment: I don't think you don't need the `<`

Comment: You are absolutely right, @TomFenech, I thought it was needed. Thanks!

Comment: `cut` is more appropriate here +1

Comment: Strong-quoting the comma (to tell sed this is the separator it has to use) is also unnecessary, at least in Bash, because the comma is no special character.

Comment: Yes I agree! Just felt like trying it with `awk`, as it was also tagged with this.

Answer (score 3):

the **cut** commandline is rather simple and well suited in your case:

```
cut -d, -f1-6 yourfile
```

So everybody agrees to say that the **cut** way is the best way to go in this case. But we can also talk about the **awk** solution, and there I may point out that in fedorqui's answer, a clever trick is used to silence empty lines (`NF` as a selection pattern), but it has the disadvantage of e.g. removing blank lines from the original file. I propose below another solution (en passant, using the `-F` option instead of the variable passing mechanism on `FS` that preserves any empty line and also respects lines with less than 6 fields, e.g. prints these lines without adding extra commas there:

```
awk -F, '{min=(NF>6?6:NF); for (i=1;i<=min-1;i++) printf "%s,", $i; printf "%s\n", $6}' yourfile
```

This works nicely because printf-ing `$6` is never an error, even in case the line has less than 6 fields. This is true with my **gawk** 4.0.1, at least...

Comment: Good one, note you can also use `printf "%s%s", $i, FS` instead of hardcoding the comma. This way, if FS changes you won't have to change it in `printf`.

Comment: Well spotted! Thanks.